# Bootstrap-Notify - Hook into events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, bootstrap-notify

### Introduction

I'm using the [Bootstrap-Notify script](https://github.com/mouse0270/bootstrap-notify) to display great visual alerts to my users. But to use the full strength of the script I want to hook into the [events of the script](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/#documentation-settings). Unfortunately, there is no example either in the documentation or on other open-source platforms like GitHub.

---

### My approach

As described in the Documentation I've linked above, I used the `onClose` attribute together with a function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Notifications
  var welcome = $.notify({
    message: "Test"
  }, {
    onClose: test()
  });
});

function test() {
  console.log("onClose");
}
```

I've made a [short fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ue3rqzn0/) to show you that it doesn't work as thought (in my case the `test` function which should be called on close of the notification triggers already on script start). Other approaches like `welcome.onClose(test());` also failed.

---

**So, how to hook into the events of Bootstrap-Notify succesfully?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not passing a **reference** to `test` as the notify `onClose` function, you are passing the **result** of the function!

you want to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Notifications
  var welcome = $.notify({
    message: "Test"
  }, {
    onClose: test
  });
});
```

or if you only wanted to modify the `test` function (and not the $.notify part), you would need to do this:

```
function test() {
  return function() {
     console.log("onClose");
  };
}
```

the argument to `onClose` should be a function

Comment: Wow, that was easier than thought! It works now, thanks. Will accept the answer after the grace period!

Comment: stackoverflow now has a grace period?!

Comment: Yeah, you can accept an answer only when at least 10 minutes have passed after you asked the question

Comment: How to get something from that notification (like settings or message etc.) in that onClose function?